# Warum gilt das Wort "Studenten" als Maskulinum?

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, gender-neutrality

Ich will keine Debatte anstoßen zum Sinn und Unsinn von geschlechtergerechter Sprache.

Vielmehr verstehe ich nicht, wieso Substantive im Plural überhaupt als männlich oder weiblich angesehen werden.

Im Gegensatz zu romanischen Sprachen hängt im Deutschen im Plural die Deklination nicht vom Geschlecht ab. Männliche und weibliche Nomen werden genau auf die gleiche Weise in Sätze eingebettet. Oder irre ich mich da?

Man könnte jetzt natürlich sagen, *Studenten* ist männlich, weil es der Plural von *Student* ist. Aber *eine Studentin, viele Studenten* widerspricht meinem Sprachgefühl überhaupt nicht. Ebensowenig, wenn jemand eine Gruppe von Frauen als *Studenten* bezeichnet.

Also, warum kann man nicht sagen, dass die Wort *Studentin* zwei Pluralformen hat, von denen es sich eine mit dem Wort *Student* teilt? Die einzige Asymetrie liegt darin, dass es ein Äquivalent zu *Studentinnen* auf männlicher Seite nicht gibt. Aber wenn das das Problem ist, könnte man sich auch einfach darauf einigen, die spezifisch weiblichen Pluralformen nicht mehr zu verwenden.

Etwas hochtrabend könnte man die Frage auch formulieren als:

---

Warum wird *Studenten* als "generisches Maskulinum" bezeichnet und nicht einfach als "Generikum"?

---

Die Wikipedia-Seite zu "generisches Maskulinum" ist riesengroß und unübersichtlich, ich denke nicht, dass das da beantwortet wird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Es ist ein bisschen spitzfindig, aber tatsächlich ist das einer der Gründe dafür, warum ich die unübliche Bezeichnung **„maskulines Generikum“** gegenüber dem verbreiteten Begriff **„generisches Maskulinum“** bevorzuge. Da das nicht der etablierten Nomenklatur entspricht, findet es sich natürlich nicht in den einschlägigen Wikipedia-Artikeln [Generisches Maskulinum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum) und [Geschlechtergerechte Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache) („[Theoriefindung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Keine_Theoriefindung)“ oder *original research*).

Allerdings gibt es nur sehr wenige echte maskuline Generika (z.B. *der Mensch, Gast*), denn die meisten sind **Pseudogenerika** (bspw. bei [Bär2004](http://www.baer-linguistik.de/beitraege/genus_und_sexus.pdf)), weil movierbar (z.B. *Student**in**, Anw**ä**lt**in**, Richter**in**, Zeug**in**, Folter**in*** und je nach Definition auch *Angeklagte**r***). 
Es gibt auch nicht besonders viele lexemische feminine oder neutrale Generika (z.B. *die Person; das Opfer*), allerdings sind viele Ableitungsmorpheme für Abstrakta, die ggf. auch für Personen oder Funktionen verwendet werden können, feminin (z.B. *die Leit**ung***); ebenso gebundene Komponenten (z.B. *Lehr**kraft**, Haushalts**hilfe***).

*Student* ist danach also ein maskulines und *Studenten* ein plurales Pseudogenerikum, *Studentin* ein feminines und *Studentinnen* ein plurales Spezifikum. Beide Spezifika sind semantisch weiblich. Die Pseudogenerika sind gerade deswegen „pseudo“, weil ohne Kontext nicht eindeutig entschieden werden kann, ob sie semantisch geschlechtsneutral oder männlich sind.

- **Bär2004**: Jochen A. Bär: *Genus und Sexus. Beobachtungen zur sprachlichen Kategorie „Geschlecht“.* ([PDF](http://www.baer-linguistik.de/beitraege/genus_und_sexus.pdf)) Seite 148–175 in:
  Karin M. Eichhoff-Cyrus: *Adam, Eva und die Sprache. Beiträge zur Geschlechterforschung* = Duden. Thema Deutsch Band 5, 2004, ISBN: 3-411-04211-7

Comment: Das ist genau die Art von Antwort, auf die ich gehofft hatte. Ich mache also den Haken dran. Das soll aber keinen davon abhalten, auf dem selben Niveau einen anderen Standpunkt darzulegen.