# Ist Bibi Blocksberg unser bester Freund?

Tags: word-usage, phrase, gender

Viele kennen sicher noch die Hörspiele von Bibi Blocksberg und das bekannte Intro mit den Zeilen:

> Bibi Blocksberg, die kleine Hexe, kann so manches, wovon ihr träumt.
>   Und sie wird euch immer helfen, denn sie ist euer bester Freund.

- [Altes Intro von 1988](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtkbcn3LCf0&t=32s)
- [Aktuelleres Intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5MpJ440dOs&t=44s)

Jetzt wissen wir, dass Bibi Blocksberg eindeutig weiblich ist. Wie kommt es jetzt dazu, dass Bibi im Intro als *bester Freund* besungen wird und nicht als *beste Freundin?*

- War die Unterscheidung im Jahre 1988, als das Intro geschrieben wurde, noch nicht so wichtig?
- Kann der Ausdruck bester Freund als eine Art generisches Maskulinum gesehen werden der beide Geschlechter einschließt? War es damals so oder auch noch heute?
- War es Marketing und kleine Jungs sollten nicht abgeschreckt werden? Stichwort: Bäh, Mädchen, ich will keine Freundin (Wie gesagt, Text ist von 1988). Zielgruppe sind schließlich Kinder zwischen 4–10 Jahren.
- Ist schlussendlich alles dem Reimschema geschuldet und/oder es reimt sich auch einfach nichts vernünftiges auf Freundin?
- Oder ist etwas ganz anderes der Grund?

Comment: Auch 1988 wurde auf geschlechtergerechte Sprache geachtet.

Comment: Man sagt ja auch ***Die Polizei, dein Freund und Helfer***, nicht etwa *Die Polizei, deine Freundin und Helferin*. Das spricht dafür, dass "Freund" geschlechtsneutral verstanden werden kann. Wenn man will, kann man diese geschlechterübergreifende Verwendung von technisch gesehen genusbehafteten Wörtern auch sehen in: ***Alle Menschen werden Brüder***.

Comment: Es sollte sich langsam rumgesprochen haben, dass *grammatisches* und *biologisches* Geschlecht in der deutschen Sprache nicht viel miteinander zu tun haben.

Comment: @Tofro Wenn das mal keine grammatikalische Revolution hervorruft, ich glaube damit wirst du dir nicht gerade Freunde machen, Ups: Freundinnen.

Comment: @Thomas *Die* Revolution hätte schon vor 1000 oder mehr Jahren stattfinden müssen - Das ist nämlich schon mindestens solange so.

Comment: In den vergangenen 1000 Jahren nicht statt gefundene Revolutionen sind kein Grund für deren Ausbleiben, wäre ja noch schöner.

Comment: Das genau ist die Kritik der feministischen Linguistik und wenn wir es noch so oft aufs Tapet bringen, werden wir diese Diskussion hier nicht zu Ende führen. Zur Vertiefung und wen es interessiert [Wikipedia: Geschlechtergerechte Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache). Und nun zurück zum Thema: was haben sich die Macher von Bibi Blocksberg gedacht? Bitte um **Antworten**.

Comment: Siehe auch hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30372/warum-gilt-das-wort-studenten-als-maskulinum

Comment: Die Macher haben gedacht: "Was reimt sich auf träumt? Ach ja, Freund."

Comment: Worüber ma sich nicht alles aufregen kann.
@BjörnFriedrich hat da recht, eine größere Überlegung wirds da nicht gegeben haben.

Comment: Siehe auch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23616/1696).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nehmen wir folgendes Paradigma des generischen Maskulinums:

- Bezieht sich ein generischer Ausdruck auf Personen beiderlei Geschlechts, nutzt man das Maskulinum.
- Bezieht sich ein generischer Ausdruck nur auf weibliche Personen, nutzt man das Femininum.
- Bezieht sich ein generischer Ausdruck nur auf männliche Personen, nutzt man das Adjektiv *männlich* oder etwas ähnliches.

(Der Gedanke dahinter ist, dass der erste, mit Abstand häufigste Fall der einfachste ist, und man zugleich Frauen nur ausschließen kann, indem man es explizit macht.)

Unter diesem Paradigma ergibt die Verwendung durchaus Sinn:
Wir möchten eben ausdrücken, dass Bibi nicht nur die Damenkonkurrenz um unsere beste Freundschaft für sich entschieden hat, sondern selbst unseren besten männlichen Freund aussticht.
Oder mit anderen Worten: Das Geschlecht spielt keine Rolle; niemand kann Bibi in Sachen Freundschaft das Wasser reichen.
Hätten wir stattdessen gesagt, dass Bibi unsere beste Freundin wäre, wäre nicht klar gewesen, ob vielleicht unser bester Freund Franz nicht noch viel besser wäre.

Comment: Genau so. Gut auf den Punkt gebracht.

Answer (score -2):

*Grammatisch* ist das einfach falsch. Natuerlich sind grammatisches und biologisches Geschlecht nicht notwendigerweise identisch. Das ist hier aber unerheblich, da auch Bibis grammatisches Geschlecht mit Sicherheit Femininum ist. Denn

> * *Hast du Bibi gesehen? Ich möchte ihn was fragen.*

ist sicher falsch, richtig hingegen

> Hast du Bibi gesehen? Ich moechte sie was fragen.

Was beweist, dass Bibis Genus Feminimum ist. Damit ist der Satz grammatisch falsch, weil er die Genus-Kongruenz zwischen der grammatisch femininen *Bibi* und dem grammatisch maskulinen *Freund* verletzt.

Genus-Kongruenz ist nicht in allen Verwendungen von *sein* obligatorisch, etwa in den Beispielen, die hier in den Kommentaren erwaehnt werden, so auch in dem von RHa genannten Beispiel

> Der Maifeiertag ist eine gute Gelegenheit, einen Ausflug zu machen.

Genus-Kongruenz ist aber im vorliegenden Fall gefordert, weil hier die *Identitaet* zweier Gegenstaende behauptet wird. Damit muessen diese Gegenstaende die gleichen Eigenschaften haben. "Freund" ist aber fuer maskuline Freunde vorgesehen, der Satz

> * *Mein Freund ist nett. Sie gibt mir immer von ihrer Schokolade etwas ab.*

waere falsch.

Das von Christian Geiselmann im Kommentar erwaehnte

> Die Polizei, dein Freund und Helfer.

ist ein etwas anders gelagerter Fall, weil hier generisches Maskulinum auf die Gruppe der Polizist*innen angewandt wird.

Generisches Maskulinum ist hier ausgeschlossen, da es sich um eine konkretisierten, individualisierten Referenten handelt.

Im Fall von Bibi kann man es als dichterische Freiheit durchgehen lassen, was in diesem Fall bedeutet: Es ist einfach nach dem Schema »Reim dich oder ich fress dich« gereimt. Aber natürlich ist die Frage »Was haben sich die Macher*innen gedacht« rein spekulativ und kann hier daher nicht wirklich beantwortet werden.

Comment: Es geht doch nicht darum, ob Bibi grammatikalisch feminin ist, sondern dass _Freund_ grammatikalisch maskulin ist. Denn sonst wäre nach derselben Logik _Bibi, das Mädchen ..._ falsch.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Das verstehe ich nicht. Warum sollte "der Freund" nicht grammatisch maskulin sein? Hat ja den maskulinen bestimmten Artikel.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich und wie wäre es dann mit: """Bibi, das Mädchen, ist dein Freundin"? oder "Das Mädchen ist dein Freund"?

Comment: @Beta, warum fragst du mich? Der Antwortende stellt doch hier einen Zusammenhang her, nicht ich.

Comment: *Sein* verlangt keine Kongruenz bezüglich des Geschlechts. Das kann man z.B. an einem Satz sehen wie *Der Maifeiertag ist eine gute Gelegenheit, einen Ausflug zu machen*, wo der Maifeiertag männlich, die Gelegenheit aber weiblich ist.

Comment: @RHa Das stimmt. Ich habe meine Aussage nun genauer formuliert, um den Unterschied zu diesen Faellen deutlicher zu machen.